# Blender 2.8 - Cannot move certain vertices in X and Y (but they can be still moved in Z)

Tags: vertices

I have this weird problem: impossible to move any of the selected vertices in X, nor in Y (but I can move them in Z). However, I can move any other vertex in any direction I want. I closed the program, started it again, but to no avail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suppose you use a Mirror modifier, try unchecking "Clipping" in the modifier parameters.

Comment: Thibsert, thanks a lot!!! Indeed, I used a Mirror modifier - and those vertices where right on the mirror axis, that's why I couldn't move them. Problem solved!